# $P(A^c \mid B)$ vs $P(B \mid A^c)$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Given a population, the <s>probability</s> event that a person is carrying a virus is $A$. When someone takes a test, the <s>probability</s> event that the test will come back positive is $B$. If asked to calculate the probability that a test will give a falsely-positive result, would you evaluate $P(A^c \mid B)$ or $P(B \mid A^c)$ ?

When presented the problem, I calculated the second probability, but looking at the answers, I found out that the prof. calculated the first one, and most of the time those two will be different. I can't imagine it's up to everyone to interpret it as they understand it, so, is it the question a bit unclear, or am I missing something?

Comment: Neither.  The probability that a test gives a falsely positive result would be $\Pr(A^c\cap B)$

Answer (score 3):

$\Pr(A^c\mid B)$ is for when it is *given* a test showed that the person tested positive, what the probability that the person does not carry the virus, i.e. we are only asking the question to people who tested positive.

$\Pr(B\mid A^c)$ is for when it is *given* the person does not carry the virus, what the probability they test positive, i.e. we are only asking the question to people who do not carry the virus.

$\Pr(A^c\cap B)$ is the probability that a person both tests positive and does not have the virus, i.e. we are asking all people regardless of status.

The way you phrased your question, "*If asked to calculate the probability that a test will give a falsely-positive result*" sounds to me as asking what the probability of having both a positive result and not carrying the virus and *asking this question to the population at large*, hence $\Pr(A^c\cap B)$.

If you wanted to ask "*calculate the probability that a test will give a falsely-positive result* **given that ____**" that is an entirely different question and will give different answers depending on what is put in the blank.

Comment: I understand the difference between each probability, but thanks nevertheless for clarifying what they mean. If I get this correctly, it is a problem of how the question is phrased, since me, you and the prof. all gave different meanings to it. I tend to agree with you, since $P(A^c \mid B)$ would mean sth like "prob. that  a person does not carry the virus given their test is positive", and $P(B \mid A^c)$ means "prob. that the test of someone that we know is healthy will come back positive".